# set value for the built in properties episerver, StopPublish

Tags: episerver, episerver-10

Im trying to enforce the user to set a DateTime for StopPublish

```
[Required]     
public virtual DateTime EnforceStopPublish
{ get; set; }

    public override DateTime? StopPublish
    {
        get { return EnforceStopPublish; }
    }
```

didn't work, is there another possible way, maybe by an Publishing event? example.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Never tried it on the `StopPublish` property (not sure about any side-effects), but could you do it with standard data annotations, i.e. a `Required`attribute on your overriding property?

Comment: Yes i tried with the Required attribute but it didn’t work. It work when setting it on a publishing event

Comment: Yes, wiring up the `OnPublishing` event is a great way to apply custom logic for validation.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do it in the SetDefaultValues method. The user will then of course be able to remove or change the stoppublishdate, but that can certanly be ok in a lot of cases.

```
public override void SetDefaultValues(ContentType contentType)
{
    base.SetDefaultValues(contentType);
    this[MetaDataProperties.PageStopPublish] = DateTime.Now.AddDays(5);
}
```